# Data changes in RavenDB by itself

Tags: ravendb

I have set up a RavenDB for evaluation. I wrote some code which pushed some documents into it. I then have a web site which renders those documents.

Throughout the day, I used the Raven Studio to modify some text in those documents, so that I could see the changes come through in my web site.

Problem: It seems that after going home for the night, when I come in the next day my database has changed - my documents have reverted to the 'pre-changed' versions... what's going on??
I've looked through the Raven console output, and there were no update commands issued on my developer machine overnight (nor would I expect there to be!!)

Note: this is just running on my development machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, RavenDB has no code in it that would automatically undo commited write operations and honestly, this would really scare me. Altogether this sounds really weird and I can't think of a scenario where that could actually happen. I suggest you send the logfiles to ravendb support if it happens again, because this would be a *really* serious issue.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I was thinking that perhaps there was some 'index rebuilding' going on as a low frequency schedule, which meant when I was seeing data I thought was correct, it was actually a 'stale' index  - and the next day was the 'correct' data. But even this doesnt make sense. I will keep a close eye on it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My colleague had this very problem with updates being reverted. The update we made was to add a property, and then also a document specific value for this property, to all the documents. We called SaveConfiguration() and saw the change being done in the Raven Studio. A while later some of the documents had lost it's new property.

I decided to turn on the logging and therefore added an NLog.config file, to get the logging started I touched the web.config. This of course restarted the application, and "voila", the updates appeared in the Raven Studio again.

After a while they disappeared from the Raven Studio, so I assumed that this was a studio problem. I therefore tried to retrieve the objects from the database in a test controller, unfortunately the objects were lacking the property value here too, so it wasn't just a studio problem.

With the logging turned on we updated the documents of the specific type again, and according to the logs and also the studio we actually updated the documents. Not long thereafter the documents reverted by losing it's added property yet again (my colleague started crying at this point - true story)..

Later I came to realize that this was all because of our live web application still had the old version of the object. When it was read in the web application the data was returned without the extra property. Because of this it seems like our DocumentSession thought that the object had changed (in all fairness), so when we called SaveChanges even these objects was written to the database - without it's extra property.

Is my conclusion correct? What is the solution to this problem? I'm thinking CQRS, because then we will never call "SaveChanges()" on the DocumentSession for reads.

Answer (score 0):

Adam,
Just making sure, did you call SaveChanges() after you made your modifications?

There is absolutely nothing in RavenDB that would cause this behavior.

Comment: Hi - yes, absolutely saved changes. I used a .net application to save documents to Raven - and saved changes. I then rendered these documents in an ASP.NET application - all good. I then modified the document in Raven Studio, and the changes showed up in my web application - all good. Then at some point the documents that I have 'touched' vanished. Perhaps it was related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421839/ravendb-entity-naming ? Since I changed my document-id format so that I didnt experience the entity-naming issue, I havent 'lost' any documents yet...