# RavenDb entity naming

Tags: ravendb

I am using RavenDB, and I save my documents (which come from a C# class called "FeedPost") with the id: "Posts/[GUID]" (where [GUID] is a guid).

Raven DB creates a document, and sets its entity-name to "FeedPosts". Ok - fine.
How come, when I go in to Raven Studio and modify a document, the entity-name for that document CHANGES from "FeedPosts" to "Posts"?

I BELIEVE it is looking at the Id of the document, but I havent asked it to change the entity-name - why does it just choose to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adam,
It shouldn't be doing that, we had a bug in the unstable version that would do something similar, but it was fixed and was never in a stable version.

What build are you using?

Comment: Hi Ayende. I took this from the server console "Build 888, Version 1.0.0 / 7d12f31"

I obtained my version of the entire Raven tool-set through Nuget.

Thanks